# CSS2DOBJECT how to set its render order to be occluded by other mesh

Tags: css, three.js

As many others implemented the css2dobject for setting markups in the scene, I decided to implemented it too. It turns out that the object is always visible even if its occluded by other meshes as seems in following picture:
[image]

And this is it's originally location:

[image]

So the question is how can I set the render order for the css2dobjects so they are not visible when occluded by those walls in this case.

All the best,
Miguel G.

source code:

```
    const css2dpreview = new CSS2DObject(
      htmlPreview
    );
css2dpreview.position.copy(intPt);
css2dpreview.renderOrder = -1;
viewer.scene.get().add(css2dpreview);
```

Comment: css2dobject is rendered as HTML elements, so it have own dom element and it can't be ocluded with objects in 3D scene. It could be only behind 3d canvas or in front of 3D canvas. It's using css 3d transform to simulating rotations etc. If you want ocluded tags in 3D you must put texture on plane and use plane in 3D scene.